# How to select a value from an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping, state

I'm having trouble figuring out how to select a value from an object in my state array. I have this following array:

```
[
 {
  name: bench,
  weight: 200,
  percentages: [200,...]
 },
 {
  name: squat,
  weight: 300,
  percentages: [300,...]
 }
]
```

and on my app I want to be able to select the weight or percentages of an object based off the name. For example, if I select 'bench', I want to get '200' and '[200,...]' in return. Right now I am mapping over the array and am getting every weight and percentages regardless of which name I choose. How can I get only the ones from the corresponding name? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for filter? `yourArray.filter(e => e.name === "bench")`? Is `bench` a string? Please share your attempt and a little bit more code if you can.

Comment: Or if you know it is only a single element use `find()` rather than `filter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array.find()` searches the array and returns the first element that matches the condition:

```js
const data = [
 {
  name: "bench",
  weight: 200,
  percentages: [200,400]
 },
 {
  name: "squat",
  weight: 300,
  percentages: [300,600]
 }
];

const selected = data.find((e) => e.name === "bench");
console.log("Weight", selected.weight);
console.log("Percentages", selected.percentages);
```